# Multipart Regex: Mix of exact and non-exact phrases

Tags: python, regex

I am building a ML training dataset from a corpus using some chemical named entities.

The reason I mention the chemical context is just to assure that this is a realistic example of what I am dealing with, not a made up one.

In doing so, I need a regex expression that has the following structure:

1 - Starts by the chemical formula string "2h-tetrazolium, 2,2'-(3,3'-dimethoxy[1,1'-biphenyl]-4,4'-diyl)bis[3-(4-nitrophenyl)-5-phenyl-,chloride (1:2)"
2 - followed by 0 up to 15 characters
3 - followed by the chemical code string "298-83-9"
4 - followed by 0 up to 15 characters
5 - followed by a non-alphanumerical character
6 - followed by the string "5"
7 - ends with a non-alphanumerical value.

The reason that I added the non-alphanumerical requirements #5 and #7 is that the text in which the regex search is to be performed is a long messy text and I wanted to ensure that the string "5" is not part of another entity such as these two examples: "bluh bluh 298-83-9 bluh bluh 564" or "bluh bluh 298-83-9 bluh bluh 645".

The way I approached was building an expression like the following:

```py
reg_exp = name_entity[0] + r".{0,15}\s*" + name_entity[1] + r".{0,15}\s*" + r"[^a-zA-Z\d]+" + name_entity[2] + r"[^a-zA-Z\d]+"
```

where name_entity is the array that contains the strings in requirements 1, 3, and 6.

However, the issue is that the chemical formula and code in requirements 1 and 3 have so much escaping, hyphens, etc that my expression does not work. I need a way to prompt regex in thinking that name_entity elements are to be treated as exactly literal phrases, not containing some regex expression.

In case it matters, I am coding in Python.

I would appreciate your help. Here, I copy a portion of the multi-page long text that is intended to contain what the the regex expression is intended to find. The part that my python code re.findall(reg_exp, text) should find is bolded:

"composition/information on ingredients substance / mixture : mixture substance name : nbt/bcip stock solution, mbf components chemical name cas-no. concentration (% w/w) methane, 1,1'-sulfinylbis- 67-68-5 >= 50 - < 70 **2h-tetrazolium, 2,2'-(3,3'- dimethoxy[1,1'-biphenyl]-4,4'- diyl)bis[3-(4-nitrophenyl)-5-phenyl-, chloride (1:2) 298-83-9 >= 1 - < 5** actual concentration is withheld as a trade secret section 4. first aid measures general advice : do not leave the victim unattended. safety data sheet nbt/bcip stock solution version 3.0 revision date: 09-25-2019"

Comment: It might be worth considering format raw strings. This could be improved a lot with the following modifications: `fr"{entity[0]}.{{0,15}}\s*{entity[1]}.{{0,15}}\s*[^a-zA-Z\d]+{entity[2]}[^a-zA-Z\d]+"` It definitely simplified readability, and the only part you need to fix is double-bracing the number of repetitions of the pattern (`{{0,15}}`.

Comment: As for the actual escaping, `re` contains an [escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) function that does what you want: escapes all control characters to avoid them messing with the grammar, so you don't need to attempt to do it manually (a lot harder than it seems).

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments: I don't know if this constitutes a full answer until you've tried it, but my full attempt would be the following `fr"{re.escape(entity[0])}.{{0,15}}\s*{re.escape(entity[1])}.{{0,15}}\s*[^a-zA-Z\d]+{re.escape(entity[2])}[^a-zA-Z\d]+"`. This solves both the escapes and simplifies the grammar so you can see what's going on much easier. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Hi @Alexander! Thank you! I tried your answer. It does not return any errors, but it does not find any matches either.

entity = ["2h-tetrazolium, 2,2'-(3,3'-dimethoxy[1,1'-biphenyl]-4,4'-diyl)bis[3-(4-nitrophenyl)-5-phenyl-,chloride (1:2)",
 '298-83-9',
 '5']

Text = copy paste from the last paragraph of my post.

code:
import re
re.findall(reg_exp, text)

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you sure you're using the escapes properly? It works correctly on my end. Using your provided values, and doing `def regex(entity):    return fr"{re.escape(entity[0])}.{{0,15}}\s*{re.escape(entity[1])}.{{0,15}}\s*[^a-zA-Z\d]+{re.escape(entity[2])}[^a-zA-Z\d]+"` and then `re.compile(regex(entity))`, it works without issue.

Comment: This might actually need more than `re.escape`. I have old code samples that can do this (ironically, from matching chemical formulas when I was in grad school), give me like half an hour and I'll have an answer.

Comment: Hahahha that's an amazing coincidence! Thanks for posting the answer. I accepted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few issues here, but it works with the following code:

```py
def new_regex(entity):
    return fr"{re.escape(entity[0])}.{{0,15}}\s*{re.escape(entity[1])}.{{0,15}}\s*[^a-zA-Z\d]+{re.escape(entity[2])}[^a-zA-Z\d]+"


entity = [
    "2h-tetrazolium, 2,2'-(3,3'- dimethoxy[1,1'-biphenyl]-4,4'- diyl)bis[3-(4-nitrophenyl)-5-phenyl-, chloride (1:2)",
    '298-83-9',
    '5'
]

n = "composition/information on ingredients substance / mixture : mixture substance name : nbt/bcip stock solution, mbf components chemical name cas-no. concentration (% w/w) methane, 1,1'-sulfinylbis- 67-68-5 >= 50 - < 70 2h-tetrazolium, 2,2'-(3,3'- dimethoxy[1,1'-biphenyl]-4,4'- diyl)bis[3-(4-nitrophenyl)-5-phenyl-, chloride (1:2) 298-83-9 >= 1 - < 5 actual concentration is withheld as a trade secret section 4. first aid measures general advice : do not leave the victim unattended. safety data sheet nbt/bcip stock solution version 3.0 revision date: 09-25-2019"

regex = new_regex(entity)
regex.findall(n)

#  ["2h-tetrazolium, 2,2'-(3,3'- dimethoxy[1,1'-biphenyl]-4,4'- diyl)bis[3-(4-nitrophenyl)-5-phenyl-, chloride (1:2) 298-83-9 >= 1 - < 5 "]
```

This was fixed by using `re.escape`, as well as fixing a few issues with whitespace in your chemical formula. You likely however want to change your entities to handle whitespace better.

Comment: The code that you posted here works - I just changed the last line to re.findall(regex, n). Thank you for your support! I think I understand the idea of using re.escape statement. I also see that changed some white space in the formula and I can see why. All good!